# Get PHP page name with all the get information

Tags: php

I want to extract the page name with the link.

Say this is the page being viewed: example.php?id=5&name=John
I want to variable to be stored that exactly, not just example.php

Thanks

Comment: Do You mean whole url, domain or name param?

Comment: I just need that above, example.php?id=5&name=john.

Comment: However, id and name are sometimes not there depending on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in variable:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Also, the `id` and `name` pieces will be stored in $_GET, so you can get them from there, no pun intended.

Comment: I am using it for a refresh page, and there isn't always variables.

Comment: @DevynShoe: I'm not sure I follow. Firstly, on every request, $_SERVER will be set, period. Secondly, if you're saying there are no variables in $_GET, then no big deal, right? Just nothing to log.

Comment: okay, well here:
On my header, if you click refresh, i want it to refresh the whole page.
on the atk.php page, there is sometimes an id.
on the list.php page, there is nothing.
I don't want to push refresh and go to list.php?id= since there isn't any information in the get.
Is that any better?

Comment: @DevynShoe: If your page loads with any get parameters populated, then a refresh will simply keep them in the URL. A refresh should never take you to a different page, that's either a link or a redirect. If you have http://site.com?id=3, and you hit refresh, it's going to reload http://site.com?id=3. It's not going to go to a different page. This is an advantage GET has over POST. It maintains its history more transparently, without an annoying 'Are you sure you want to resend data' popup.

Comment: I am using it within an app on facebook, so if they click refresh, it will reload the index.php page by default. 
This is the reason I am trying to make a refresh page.